# Share GCP KMS key among projects

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-kms

I created a keyring and key in one of my GCP projects and I would like to share the key to others project i.e. the key can be used to encrypt the storage bucket.
Does anyone know the steps to share the key among GCP projects?

Answer (score 1):

I just found out I have to copy the key resource name and paste it when selecting the key in the storage bucket.